# HTML formatting Arabic text letters

Tags: html, css, arabic

I want to color some letters in an Arabic text, for instance this text:

> إذا ماطمحت إلى غاية

that gives me this normal text:

[image]

So I put some letters in tags to color them:

**HTML:**

```
إذا <b>م</b>اط<b>م</b>حت إلى <b>غ</b>اية
```

**CSS:**

```
b {
    color: #e74c3c;
}
```

and this gave me:

[image]

But I want it to give a normal readable Arabic text like that:

[image]

I tried changing font but it seems to be the same problem with all fonts so the issue is not in fonts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding a [zero-width joiner Unicode character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) before the opening span tag.
You should check this in all browsers, as it is an issue that some can't cope with.

Comment: thanks that works but instead of adding it before the opening tag I added it inside the tag.

Answer (score 4):

I have a test here, but I find small cuts between red color letters and following letter:

```
إذا <b>م&zwj;</b>ا ط<b>م&zwj;</b>حت إلى <b>غ&zwj;</b>اية
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/bhallak/hrzqsuok/#&togetherjs=5BM1mhtB0n)

Comment: you should add the symbol before and after every letter you want to make in joined form so in this code you have to join ا (alif) with the م (mim) before it, ط (ta) with م (mim) after it, ح (ha) with the same م (mim) that is before it and the ا (alif) with the غ (ghayn) before it...
And this is the code:
` إذا <b>م&zwj;</b>&zwj;ا ط&zwj;<b>م&zwj;</b>&zwj;حت إلى <b>غ&zwj;</b>&zwj;اية `

Comment: I got spaces between two character, why ?